# Word XML to HTML (Alternatives)

Tags: php, xml, xsd, ms-word

My company creates Word documents with XML tags based on a schema and then translate them to html, put them in a MySQL database, and load them on the web with PHP. The problems are, we are stuck using Word 2003. New versions of office no longer allow saving with the XML tags.

Also, there is so much junk code with WordML and VML that the pages do not display properly in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

Is there a better way to convert Word to HTML? Or is there a better alternative to using word with our XML schema?

Comment: try getting the rtf from the word 2003 and then make xml out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use either MS Word apis if with .NET (if this permits you to save files as xml format) or open office libraries. These are open source but have some differences with the word format.

Open office libraries are probably easier to use, better documented and easier to use in php. http://php.net/manual/en/java.examples-basic.php